# Validate input type based on condition

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using a html5 input

```
<Input id={cellData.column}
       defaultValue=1
       onBlur={this.onInputChange}
       placeholder="Enter text"
       ref={cellData.column}
       min="1"
       type="number" />
```

The default value is an int, when i validate it using this statement:

```
if (input && !_.isNumber(parseInt(input)) || input !== parseInt(input, 10).toString())
```

The second condition fires off as `input = 6`

Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: What are the conditions of the input?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, what do you mean by 'conditions of the input'?

Comment: What input are you expecting or what input will you not accept?